# How to migrate existing domain with ssl certificate from CentOS/Apache to Docker/Nginx?

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, ssl-certificate, migrate, domain-name

We have a site running on CentOS/PHP/Apache stack. We want to migrate the whole site to Docker/PHP-FPM/Nginx using docker-compose. 
So far we've set up plans for migrating pretty much everything except the domain and the existing ssl certificate . 
How do we go about this ?

Nginx is up and running on port 80

```
ports:
      - '9007:80'
```

How can we redirect the existing domain to the docker container and also use the existing ssl certificate ?

Answer (score 0):

No need for the hassle, someone already did the work for you:

https://github.com/evertramos/docker-compose-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion

Its a fully configured auto-ssl docker, which does basically exactly what you need. Start your Website-Container with the following additional parameters (from the git-repo):

```
docker run -d -e VIRTUAL_HOST=your.domain.com \
              -e LETSENCRYPT_HOST=your.domain.com \
              -e LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=your.email@your.domain.com \
              --network=webproxy \
              --name my_app \
              httpd:alpine
```

I can only recommend it, its a great solution for hosting multiple projects on one server.